# Calculating specific heat capacity of a carbon rod from a current passing through it

Tags: thermodynamics

I am currently doing a high school investigation which consists of calculating the specific heat capacity of a carbon rod from a current passing through it. The method used to do this is to insert a section of the rod in a constant volume of water and using a temperature probe to measure the rate of change of temperature of the water for different power values (Power calculated from the product of current and potential difference; P=IV). I am assuming all that the power applied to the water is the same as that of the carbon rod. The equation is such that:
$$Q/Δt=mcΔT/Δt$$
So that the slope of the graph between power and rate of change of temperature divided by the mass of the carbon rod gives the specific heat capacity of the carbon rod.
However, I have done all of this successfully and the slope is something surprisingly big. When I divide it by the mass of carbon that is in contact with the water, it gives me something around 160J/g·K, which is nothing close to the actual value. What is a possible reason for this? Should I have accounted for the mass of the water?[image]

Comment: what about you divide it by the mass of the water?

Answer (score 1):

The water and the rod both increase in temperature, so you need to take both into account. If you know the total amount of heat U generated, and the mass of water $m_w$ and the rod, $m_r$, and you know the heat capacity of the water $c_w$ but not of the rod $c_r$, then you have to solve this equation:

$$U = (m_w c_w + m_r c_r)\Delta T$$

Ignore the water, and everything looks like heat capacity of the rod. Which will obviously give you the wrong answer.

Because you are taking the difference between two numbers, this is a hard experiment to do well - the answer is likely to have large error bars. Make sure you spend time thinking about that.